# Flask: custom error handler not catching all exceptions

Tags: python, rest, flask

I use the following error handler in my application:

```
def make_json_error(ex):
    status_code = ex.code if isinstance(ex, HTTPException) else 500
    description = str(ex.description) if isinstance(ex, HTTPException) else 'internal server error'
    message = {'error': {'message': '{}: {}'.format(str(status_code), description)}}

    response = jsonify(message)
    response.status_code = status_code

    return response
```

which is then used when creating a Flask app:

```
for code in werkzeug.exceptions.default_exceptions:
    app.errorhandler(code)(make_json_error)
```

Curiously, it doesn't return a JSON-formatted error for certain invalid requests:

```
$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/tickets?id=a' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
{
  "error": {
    "message": "400: Invalid id parameter values"
  }
}

$ curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/tickets?id=a 1' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 400</p>
        <p>Message: Bad request syntax ('GET /api/tickets?id=a 1 HTTP/1.1').</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 400 - Bad request syntax or unsupported method.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the extra whitespace in the query string in the second command. Any ideas why this is also not handled as a regular 400 error, same as the first one? From what I can tell, the second URL is not even routed through the `/tickets` view function so I assume the whitespace is somehow specially interpreted within Flask.